# How to plot complex numbers in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I was trying to plot complex numbers in Julia but I haven't found any good way to do it yet.

Comment: As in, on a two dimensional grid? Do you want a contour of a function or just a handful of points? Or are you trying to do something fancy with 3D to plot a function in a fuller way?

Answer (score 4):

```
using PyPlot
nums = ComplexF64.([1,2,4],[2,2,-1])
polar.(Base.vect.(0.0,angle.(nums)),Base.vect.(0.0,abs.(nums)),marker="o")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but I can't get this code to work because it shows a problem with pyplot backend in Julia, related to matplotlib that I havent found a fix yet.

Comment: Try: ``using Conda; Conda.runconda(`install -c conda-forge matplotlib`)``

Comment: I tried your code and some tips from https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/369 and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to plot the real and imaginary part as x and y

```
julia> using Plots

julia> d = [0.0000000+0.0000000im, 0.1111111+0.0000000im,
            0.1666667+0.0962250im, 0.2222222+0.0000000im,
            0.3333333+0.0000000im, 0.3888889+0.0962250im,
            0.3333333+0.1924501im, 0.4444444+0.1924501im,
            0.5000000+0.2886751im, 0.5555556+0.1924501im,
            0.6666667+0.1924501im, 0.6111111+0.0962250im,
            0.6666667+0.0000000im, 0.7777778+0.0000000im,
            0.8333333+0.0962250im, 0.8888889+0.0000000im,
            1.0000000+0.0000000im]

julia> plot(real(d),imag(d))
# or directly with plot(d)
```

[image: plot complex numbers]

Comment: @mcabbott This is in principle a first shot in the dark until we get further info from the OP.

Comment: Sure, maybe the `plot(d)` shortcut is all I meant to add.